# Visual Studio make form background opacity to .5

Tags: winforms, opacity

With Visual Studio, I'm trying to make a form, and the window background I want to have a 50% opacity to.  Problem is, if I set the form's opacity to 50% the whole thing goes almost invisible, and if I do the opacity key, well.... The whole window goes invisible....  Any way to make it so the window background has like a 50% opacity, while the content inside has 100% opacity?

Hopefully this makes sense to you guys.  Thanks in advance! :)